# Rails form texteditor for haml language

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, haml

Are there any good texteditor's for haml language, for example as jce in joomla etc?

Now i use ckeditor for my form:

```
= form_for [:admin, @va] do |f|
  - if @va.errors.messages.values.present?
    .warning
      - @va.errors.messages.values.each do |msg|       
        - msg.each do  |m|
          %li= m
  = f.label "Артикул:"
  = f.text_field :article
  = f.label "Описание:"
  = f.cktext_area :description, :value => :article, :ckeditor => {:language => "ru"}
```

But this editor work's only with default html language, but could i transform it to use haml language? And how? Maybe in controller something like:

```
def create
    @va = VinAnswer.new(params[:vin_answer])
    @va.description (and here somehow use this gem [https://github.com/haml/html2haml][1], but also how to be with edit method... ?)
    if @va.save
      AdminSendNewAnswerMailer.new_vin_answer(@vq, @va, @vin.vin_number, @user).deliver
      redirect_to  admin_vin_question_path(:id => params[:vin_question_id]) # redirect if saved.
    end
  end
```

So how can i use ckeditor when i use haml as my markup language?

Comment: @user1737909  didn't understand you, what do you mean?

Comment: the exact same way as you'd do with a html layout

Comment: @user1737909   then it stores in db like: <p>something</p> bla bla bla,   but need something like %p  /n something

Comment: would do the same with an html layout.

Comment: @user1737909 give code, i could understand what you mean (for me now you say something like Cap Obl.)

Comment: Ah, you want to generate HAML from ckeditor ? There's a html2haml gem, but I don't know why you want that

Comment: @user1737909 yes, i need it, becouse i use as my markup - haml, and page content is stored in db, when i fetch from db <p>something</p>  i see it without formatting for some reasons

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the same way. The thing you're asking here is : how to display unescaped content.
Because with either "

a

" or "%p a", you're gonna get the same result.
You're looking for `!=` :

`%p!= article.content`